# chrome extension : Stop loading the page on launch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to stop the page loading when I click the extension icon. I have a background page , I need an option similar to window.stop() when I click the extension Icon. If the main page is still in loading condition stop loading and load the content JavaScript of extension should work.

Comment: If Xan's solution does not work, try `chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:'javascript:void window.stop();'})` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always do this (requires host permissions or [`activeTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab)):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: "window.stop();",
        runAt: "document_start"
    });
});
```

I am not sure what happens with manifest-defined content scripts. It's possible that scripts defined with `run_at` other than `document_start` will not be injected; in this case you can use `executeScript`'s callback to inject them in any case, and put in some guard code in the content script to prevent it from executing twice:

```
// content.js
if(contentInjected) return;
var contentInjected = true;

/* rest of the code */
```

Comment: No. the code chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "window.stop"}); don't works. here the execute script does not affect the the reloading tab.

Comment: also I have a $.ajax() inside the chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

Comment: Don't forget to add `()` after `window.stop` ;)

Comment: @RobW and probably `run_at`.. Can't edit right now, can you fix?

Comment: @RobW I dont have a content script. The window.stop()on background.js does'not work

Comment: @abhilash The code at the top of this answer should be run from the background page. Then click on the button to stop the page load. If it doesn't work for frames, try adding `allFrames:true`.