# Chrome Extension Stop Loading Pages after Number of Seconds

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is similar to this post but I don't know how to get it working without the click action:

[chrome extension : Stop loading the page on launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119027/chrome-extension-stop-loading-the-page-on-launch)

I want to create a Chrome extension that doesn't require clicking to work. So I want it it stop loading ALL pages after a set number of seconds after they've been launched.

So if the extension is installed and a new tab opens up the page will load for only 10 seconds and then stop loading.

**How can I stop pages from loading after X seconds on all pages via  chrome extension?**

Comment: _"as long as it's enabled"_ And what do you mean by that? How is that state defined and stored?

Comment: I meant enabled by the user. Obviously it wouldn't do anything if it's disabled by the user. Sorry if that was confusing. I removed that reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the question you link to uses [Programmatic Injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) to add a content script to stop loading. That works great if you want it only sometimes.

If you want something with a content script to happen always, you [define it in the manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration):

> If your content script's code should always be injected, register it in the extension manifest using the `content_scripts` field

```
"content_scripts" : [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["stop.js"],
  "run_at": "document_start"
}],
```

With that, you know that `stop.js` is loaded alongside every page at the beginning of page load. Then you can implement your logic. Dead-simple solution:

```
// stop.js
setTimeout(() => {window.stop()}, 10000);
```

Note that this will trigger an install-time permission warning "Read and modify all your data on all websites you visit", since you can no longer rely on `"activeTab"` but do something without user interaction.

You may also want to consider adding `"all_frames": true` to the content script declaration if you want this to also happen in sub-frames.