# chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I very new to chrome extensions development. I want to create a simple extension that stops the browser after 10s if the page is still loading.
Here is my code :

> manifest.json

```
{
        "name": "stopLoading", 
        "version": "1.0",
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "content_scripts" : [{
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["stopLoading.js"],
          "run_at": "document_start"
        }],
        "permissions": [
            "tabs",
            "webNavigation"
        ]
}
```

> stopLoading.js

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.frameId === 0) { // vérifier si c'est l'onglet principal
    setTimeout(function() {
      chrome.tabs.get(details.tabId, function(tab) {
        if (tab.status !== "complete") {
          chrome.tabs.stop(details.tabId);
        }
      });
    }, 10000); // interruption après 10 secondes
  }
});
```

Sometime it works but a lots of errors are reported :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'onCommitted')

Could you help me to fix this pbm ?
Thank you.

Comment: Content scripts cannot use that API. [Understand content script capabilities](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#capabilities)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Norio Yamamoto. It seems that I have to use "background" but I have no clue on how to proceed. I've asket to ChatGpt :-) without success.

Comment: We do not deny that you use chatGpt, but we are not a replacement for chatGpt.

Comment: I agree. It was a joke. I'm busy to read the chrome extension documentation to find how I can archive this dev.

Comment: Remove `content_scripts` and add `"background": {"service_worker": "stopLoading.js"}`

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thank you very much for your help.
I finally changed the way to proceed, after reading this post : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467493/chrome-extension-stop-loading-pages-after-number-of-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. Finally, thank to this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467493/chrome-extension-stop-loading-pages-after-number-of-seconds), I changed the code as following...
So far, it seems to work fine.

> manifest.json

```
{
        "name": "stopLoading", 
        "version": "1.0",
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "permissions": [
            "activeTab",
            "webNavigation"
        ],
        "content_scripts" : [{
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content.js"],
          "run_at": "document_start"
        }]
}
```

> content.js

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.frameId === 0) { // vérifier si c'est l'onglet principal
    setTimeout(function() {
      chrome.tabs.get(details.tabId, function(tab) {
        if (tab.status !== "complete") {
          chrome.tabs.stop(details.tabId);
        }
      });
    }, 10000); // interruption après 10 secondes
  }
});
```