# chrome extension : pause loading the page on launch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension that will check tab domain and if this is in my blacklist, I need to show the user an HTML page that tells the user, this page is not safe! I need to **"Pause loading page"** and if user insist to access the page, make it **"Resume loading page"**

Comment: I believe there is nothing that you can use to pause/resume the loading. But you can make use of `window.stop();`

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Tvde1 No!! because didn't find anything!

Comment: In addition with @elegant-user's comment, you may check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119027/chrome-extension-stop-loading-the-page-on-launch) for additional information on how to use the  `window.stop();` method. This should be run from the background page. If that does not work, try `chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:'javascript:void window.stop();'})`.